# Solr server installed in environment

Tags: solr, server

I am new in solr server just let me know, solr server or solr cloud server working only on Linux ? or is it possible to installed the solr server in window machine.
Solr server and solr service is different.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it both on Linux and Windows, no issues .

Comment: solr server can work on windows?? can you please provide the installation and any set up examples. so i can go and do the work.  For production environment , which version is recommended ? ? window or linux

Comment: Type solr download in Google ,and you will get a zip file for Windows on their website .

Comment: For production environment which OS shall i use ? linux or windows??